# How to locate and launch other apps within an app on Mac

Tags: macos, process

I'm new here and also new to Mac Programming.

I want to **launch an app or get its url within another app**.

However，I don't know how to implementing this program without **monitoring the processes**.

The problems are:

**1.An app can be installed every where.**

**2.A process can be a system service.**

If the question isn't clear enough, please get me noticed.